# Is there a difference between "write" and "write down"?

Tags: word-difference

Is there a difference between "write" and "write down" or it's just a matter of fashion / style?

At the university I see that some of the teachers say "write down" and some of them say "write" without "down"- both are in the same context in the classes (to write notes). Is one of them better or more correct or it's just a matter of style?

Comment: Did you check [*write down*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/write+down)? Without specific context, you can't judge similarity.

Answer (score 4):

I think in your usage they basically mean the same thing.

> write down

can mean to make a formal record of *something*

> Let me **write down** your address and thine number.
>   Marriages are **written down** and recorded in a registry.

whereas

> write

has less the meaning of *recording*  and is also the actual action of *writing*

> I'll **write** you a note.
>   Let's **write** them a letter.
>   Please **write** a Thank You card to everyone who gave you a birthday present.

For example,

> Every week I *wrote* a letter to my parents and *wrote down* what happened.

Comment: How is write more informal? I would never say "Write down a note to your friend". That just sounds weird.

Comment: The act of "writing" can be for anything, "writing down" has a sense of "formally recording" and certainly to "write down *something*" one must "write" it.  One would not say "write down a note to your friend" but one would say "write down what happened in a note to your friend" or "Write it down in a note to your friend".

Comment: That doesn't make it more formal... "He wrote the great American novel" is correct. "Wrote down" would not make sense in this case. There's no element of formality here at all.

Comment: The point is that _write down_ takes a different argument from _write_. The object of _write_ can be the content, the words, the message, or the document. The object of _write down_ is the content or the words,. but not the document. That's why you can't say "Write down a note" or "Write down a letter".

Comment: @ColinFine +1 Can't "write down a letter" as in a document as opposed to "Write down a letter... A, B, C" which is possible.